# Spring-integration-aws - Readme.md is not correct?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud

I am trying to use `S3StreamingMessageSource` as per the readme.md. But this class does not seem to exist I checked the source code and all I can find is `S3InboundStreamingMessageSource`.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/blob/master/README.md

Can someone please provide me with a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name is just wrong; use the `S3InboundStreamingMessageSource`.

I opened an [issue to fix the README](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-aws/issues/54).